# Overlapping of 2 rasters to find common places of overlap of same values

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

Using QGIS, I am trying to overlap two rasters which are identically  shape and extent, but with different values. Values of my data ranges from 0-1.

I want to find the places where mine data values overlap. For example, if I want to know where 0.5 and 0.5 values overlap and where 0.75 and 0.75 overlap in my raster image.

Does anyone have an idea of how to accomplish this?

Comment: What if the overlap at one location was 0.5 and 0.5, but at another location it was 0.75 and 0.25?  Would it be a problem that both output values were 1.0?

Comment: Actually I want to trace the places only where same values overlap. Is there anyway to find them?